# Codeigniter 4 how to unset session

Tags: session, codeigniter-4

I am trying to unset user session and set user session back again after use update their profile. I keep facing issue trying to unset the user session, I keep getting errors.

I have no issue setting my session like this :

```
session()->set($data);
```

But if I unset my session like this :

```
session()->unset($data);
```

I get an error message : Call to undefined method CodeIgniter\Session\Session::unset()

Or should I just destroy session and re-set it again?

Can anyone help me out here? Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Error is pretty self explanatory : unset() function doesn't exist in Session lib in CI4. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Update session data from your user? Destroy its session because of an event like a log out action?

Comment: @ViLar Apologize for the obvious, as this is my first time touching frameworks and backend programming, I have more to learn and figure. Yes, I would like to update the session data from my user if they update their firstname, lastname, etc. CI4 has this unset function but I can't get how to use it.

Comment: [Removing Session Data](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html?highlight=#removing-session-data)

Comment: If the data changes, you can just overwrite it. Have you tried that out? You don't need to "destroy" and re-set it again.

Comment: As @TimBrownlaw said, just use `session()->set()` with the correct key and it will overwrite the previous value of the session

Comment: @TimBrownlaw Thank you! I just tried it and it work! I don't know what I have been thinking. It's so simple yet I confused myself. Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 4):

In CI4, need to do use

```
session()->remove($data);
```

further, please explore https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html?highlight=#removing-session-data

Answer (score 0):

Destroying a Session: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html?highlight=sessions#destroying-a-session

To clear the current session (for example, during a logout), you may simply use either PHP’s session_destroy() function, or the library’s destroy() method.

**Both will work in exactly the same way**:

```
<?php

session_destroy();
// or
$session->destroy();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can unset session "set" values by "remove" in CI4

```
$session->remove('some_name');
```